# which encoding shall I specify to `InputStreamReader()` and `OutputStreamWrier()` for Windows text file?

Tags: java, io

When using Java (in Linux or Windows) to read or write a Windows text file (where for example a new  line character is encoded as `/r/n`), which encoding shall I specify to `InputStreamReader()` and `OutputStreamWrier()`, so that conversion between  newline character in Java and   `/r/n` in Windows text file (and possibly other conversions) can be done correctly?

Comment: Newlines have have nothing to do with common encodings. Which encoding to use is up to you as long as reading from and writing to that file uses the same encoding.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Here I am talking about IO with Windows text files (supposed to be human readable in Windows), not arbitrary files.

Comment: arbitrary files don't need an encoding. I would suggest you go with UTF-8 unless that causes you any problems.

Comment: if go with UTF-8, will /r/n be read as it is, and will `/n` be written as it is, so no conversion?

Comment: Encoding has to do with how characters are converted to bytes and vice versa. Using a different encoding will not change which newline characters get used—only how they're encoded.

Comment: @Slaw "only how they're encoded" isn't that encoding?

Comment: Yes, that's my point. Note that `\n` is a _character_ which, when written to a file (or other stream), is converted  to _bytes_. This conversion is dependent on the encoding used, but the encoding doesn't change _what_ characters are written. Examples of encodings are: UTF-8, UTF-16, US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1, and so on. In Java these are represented by the [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class.

Comment: @Slaw A new line character (by definition, i.e. in its abstract sense, not `/n`)  is encoded in `0D0A`  in Windows and `0A` in Linux. Is that not encoding?

Comment: Yes, that is encoding. But note that `0D` is `\r` and `0A` is `\n`—on both platforms. The point is, if you used a different encoding you might end up with `FFAA` and `AA` or `0C20` and `20` or whatever, _but you'll always have the same characters_. (Note those other byte sequences are made up)

Comment: Please read [this page](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-newline) about the usage of new line in Java.